# How to reset time for data logging in micro:bit micropython

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I would like to start data logging in a bbc micro:bit with the press of its `button_a`, in order to be able to synchronize the timestamps with an external clock.
The idea is that, if I press the button at 12:10 o'clock, I would know that the first row of data (with `0.00` timestamp) was taken at that time (+/- human reaction time, of course).

The problem is that the zero time of the timestamps begin when the bbc micro:bit is turn on (or reset); so the first timestamp in the log file is not `0.00`.

Of course, I could synchronize with that *turning-on*, but I think it would not be that accurate (I'm using the micro:bit with a [robotbit board](https://www.kittenbot.cc/products/robotbit-robotics-expansion-board-for-micro-bit), which has a big 'on-off' switch.)

What I would like would be some kind of `reset_time()` method. :)

The code is this:

```
from microbit import *
import log

log.set_labels('altitude', 'azimuth', 'measure', timestamp=log.SECONDS)

# Wait until Button 'A' is pressed. This way, we can sinchronize the measures with an external clock or watch
while not button_a.was_pressed():
    pass

for altitude in...
  for azimuth in...
    measure=take_reading()
    log.add({
            'altitude': altitude,
            'azimuth': azimuth,
            'measure': measure
            })
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/lopezsolerluis/foto-teodolito-log

Comment: could it be solution, that on Button_A press you take measurements how much seconds elapsed after board started and use that value in your logging function to subtract that amount of secods from "current" time?

Comment: @Lixas It's a great solution, indeed! Although it would be more 'elegant' to be able to reset the time, I'll certainly use your approach if anything else fails. Thank you very much!